# Using the sort command in BASH in osx 10.9.4

Tags: bash, osx-mavericks

I'm running the following command in a bash shell, and the result is not sorted. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
ls /bin /usr/bin | grep -v '/bin:$'| grep -v '^$' | sort > proglist
```

Instead of a sorted list, the results are:

```
2to3
2to3-
2to3-2.7
2to32.6
BuildStrings
CpMac
DeRez
GetFileInfo
MergePef
MvMac
RSA_SecurID_getpasswd
ResMerger
Rez
RezDet
RezWack
SetFile
SplitForks
UnRezWack
[
a2p
a2p5.12
a2p5.16
addftinfo
afconvert
afhash
afida
afinfo
afmtodit
afplay
agentxtrap
agvtool
alias
allmemory
applesingle
appletviewer
apply
apr-1-config
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're sorted in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) order. Numbers come before upper case letters, which come before lower case letters. Symbols and punctuation have various places in between and around them. You can try doing `LC_COLLATE=en_US sort` and see if it gives a better result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the results ARE sorted, but they're also separated by file type...in descending order: numbers > uppercase > symbols > lowercase.

I don't have enough experience using the command line to tell you how to fix it, but that's something I would look into before trying anything drastic :)